# Oracle: How display records from 1 row to many rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with records displaying in Oracle.

For example: I have all my records display in one row, like that:

```
  id| a | a1 | b | b1
  -------------------
  1 |400|  1 |410|  3 
  2 |400| 10 |410| 30
```

But I need, that records would look like that:

```
  id| code| number
  ----------------
  1 | 400 |  1  
  1 | 410 |  3  
  2 | 400 | 10 
  2 | 410 | 30
```

Maybe I should use group by function?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine on Oracle

```
select id ,a "code" , a1 "number" from test
union all
select id, b "code",b1 "number"  from test
order by id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38eca/3)

Comment: Always use `union all` rather than `union`, unless you have a really good reason for incurring the overhead of removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Using oracle's UNPIVOT feature, you can achieve this as follows

```
WITH table_ (id, a, a1, b, b1) AS (
    SELECT 1, 400, 1, 410, 3 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 300, 4, 310, 5 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 400, 10, 410, 30 from dual)
---------
-- End of data preparation
---------    
SELECT id,
       CASE
           WHEN a1 = 'A' THEN
            a
           WHEN a1 = 'B' THEN
            b
           ELSE
            NULL
       END AS code,
       "NUMBER"
  FROM table_ unpivot("NUMBER" FOR a1 IN(a1 AS 'A', b1 AS 'B'));
```

Output:

```
| ID | CODE | NUMBER |
|----|------|--------|
|  1 |  400 |      1 |
|  1 |  410 |      3 |
|  3 |  300 |      4 |
|  3 |  310 |      5 |
|  2 |  400 |     10 |
|  2 |  410 |     30 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the syntax with [`unpivot`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDIBEFI), 
especially if you had more columns (c, c1, d, d1...):

```
select id, code, num from test 
unpivot ((code, num) for (x, y) in ((a, a1), (b, b1)))
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f389/1)